# react parent function to child using export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to do the following work in React like the title. Rendering works normally, but the function declared in the parent window is not called.

##### Parent

```
import React, { useState,useMemo, useRef,useCallback,useEffect } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
import {GridComponents} from 'components/Grids/GridOptions.js'
import {ActionCellRenderer} from 'components/Grids/ActionCellRenderer.js'
import { createItem } from "views/Components/baseInfo/commonCodeMgmt/CommonCodeItem.js";
import {BasicAlert} from 'components/Notify/AlertPage.js'

function CommonCodeMgmt() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = React.useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      var id = window.setTimeout(null, 0);
      while (id--) {
        window.clearTimeout(id);
      }
    };
  }, []);
  
  
  const hideAlert = (params) => {
    setAlert(null);
  };

    const confirmFunc = () => {
      console.log('1111');
    }

    const cellClickedListenerd = ((params) => {
              setAlert(
                <BasicAlert confirmFunc={confirmFunc}></BasicAlert>
              );
    });

    //return (redering.....);
}
```

##### Child

```
import React, { useRef,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert";

export const BasicAlert = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return(
      <SweetAlert
        warning
        style={{ display: "block", marginTop: "-100px" }}
        title= 'del'
        onConfirm={() => {props.confirmFunc}}
        // onCancel={() => {return {...params,gubun:'fail'}}}
        confirmBtnBsStyle="info"
        cancelBtnBsStyle="danger"
        confirmBtnText="doing"
        cancelBtnText="cancle"
        showCancel
      >
    del
  </SweetAlert>
  );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

When `onConfirm` is called inline code is fired, but `confirmFunc` is not called.

```
onConfirm={() => {props.confirmFunc}}
```

Either call it from inline like this:

```
onConfirm={() => {props.confirmFunc()}}
```

or pass as a handler like this:

```
onConfirm={props.confirmFunc}
```

See [Adding event handlers](https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#adding-event-handlers) for details.